# Cannot login using Facebook on IOS app

Tags: bug, status-completed, ios-app

Using an iPhone 5c with IOS 9.2 and latest version of stackexchange app, I cannot login using my Facebook account.

Comment: Any error message?

Comment: "Could not perform this request with your account. Please try logging back in. If this persists, let us know on meta."

Comment: Does your Facebook account have an email address?  Looking at the server, the error could happen if we get an error from Facebook or a response with no email.

Comment: Yes it does have an email address

Comment: On Facebook, can you go to Account Settings -> Apps -> Logged in with Facebook -> Stack Exchange iOS App -> Info You Provide and see if "Email Address" is in that list?

Comment: The new version has shipped.  You should hopefully see a more helpful error message if you're still not able to log in.

Answer (score 1):

This will be fixed (or improved) in 1.4.3.5.

The message you're receiving is because the `/me` request issued by the server either got an error or did not contain an email address.  Assuming nothing bad happened with the server, the the causes were either that you didn't give the app access to your email address or that your account doesn't have an email address.  The app now performs the following validations after getting a successful login response from Facebook:

1. If the user has declined access to the email permission, it gives them the options to add the permission or cancel.
2. Once it has the permission, it tried reading the email from /me.  If that fails, the app will display the user facing error messages (`error.error_user_title` and `error.error_user_msg`).
3. Otherwise, the app will check if the email address is nil.  If it is, it will inform the user that it couldn't find an email on the account.
4. Once these validations are complete, the API will make the same request which now shouldn't fail.  If it does, the original error message will be displayed which would then mean an issue is occurring between the API and Facebook that would affect all users.